# Pandas convert column values into different columns based on another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

### Description:

I have a pandas dataframe that contains two columns `ID` and `Value`.

I want to group the the `ID` column

and convert the group results (`Value`) into multiple columns with Numeric suffix as `Value1`, `Value2`, `Value3` and so on based on the total results.

### **Example:**

**Current DataFrame:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'], 'Value': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'] } )
df
   ID Value
0   A     A
1   A     B
2   A     C
3   B     D
4   C     E
5   C     F
6   D     G
7   E     H
8   F     I
9   F     J
10  F     K
11  F     L
```

**Expected DataFrame:**

```
  ID  Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4
0  A       A     B       C       NaN
1  B       D     NaN     NaN     NaN
2  C       E     F       NaN     NaN
3  D       G     NaN     NaN     NaN
4  E       H     NaN     NaN     NaN
5  F       I     J       K       L
```

I have tried multiple solutions with pivot table as well, but I don't get the results.

**What I tried**

```
pd.pivot(df, index='ID', columns='ID', values='Value')
```

Comment: See "question 10" in the pivot question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe

Comment: To fix your pivot code use `df.assign(count=df.groupby('ID').cumcount()).pivot('ID', 'count', 'Value')`

Comment: If you want a solution without `pivot` you can try this one-liner:
`df.groupby(["ID"])["Value"].unique().apply(pd.Series).filter(regex="\d").add_prefix('Value').reset_index()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a suitable [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```py
df.set_index(['ID', df.groupby('ID').cumcount()]).unstack().add_prefix('Value').droplevel(0, 1).reset_index()
```

Out:

```
  ID Value0 Value1 Value2 Value3
0  A      A      B      C    NaN
1  B      D    NaN    NaN    NaN
2  C      E      F    NaN    NaN
3  D      G    NaN    NaN    NaN
4  E      H    NaN    NaN    NaN
5  F      I      J      K      L
```

Comment: Wow, This is incredible. Thanks a lot for the answer, I definitely need to have a look at MultiIndex, cumcount and unstack.

Answer (score 4):

```
df=pd.pivot_table(df, index='ID', columns=df.groupby("ID").cumcount())
df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
df
```

Comment: This gives me an issue saying that `pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`. I think it happens since the values are not numeric.

Comment: Worked for me with the dataset you gave and should work for you.  Check that your value column is not of
 'object' type? the groupby operations specifically check whether each column is a numeric dtype first.

Comment: My dtypes are set as object as of now.

Comment: Those cant be aggregated then. You can `df[Value]=df[Value].astype(int)` if you want to use this method.

Comment: Okay, I will check that out as well. Thanks a lot for the inputs. Much appreciated!